# Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'IntegerProperty [value: 7]'

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I am getting this error when trying to delete from my javafx GUI that I made. And I don't know how to solve it.
Error:
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'IntegerProperty [value: 7]'

Part of my code:

setAllClear();

```
    SalesTable getSelectedRow = salesTableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    String sqlQueryDelete = "delete from sales where id = '" + getSelectedRow.getSalesTableId() + "';";
    try {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();


        statement.executeUpdate(sqlQueryDelete);
```

Comment: Your model class is incorrectly implemented. The `getSalesTableId()` method should return an `int`, not an `IntegerProperty`. You should have a `salesTableIdProperty()` method returning the `IntegerProperty`. Also, this looks like it should be a numeric column in the database, so the value should not be quoted. And finally, never build up SQL statements with string concatenation like that; use a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It works